# Firefox Addon SDK - how to make page in new tabs run only once

Tags: tabs, firefox-addon-sdk

I am new to Firefox Addon SDK, high level API.

What I wanted to do it, if a user click the icon on the toolbar, a new tab is opened, and run the script defined in contentscriptfile.

I use the script below:

```
var self = require("sdk/self");
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');

var button = buttons.ActionButton({
  id: "mm-link",
  label: "Visit mm",
  icon: {
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
  onClick: handleClick
});

function handleClick(state) {
  tabs.open("about:blank");
  tabs.on('ready', function (tab) {
    tab.attach({
      contentScriptFile: self.data.url("home.js"),
      contentScriptOptions: {"aaa" : "1111", "bob" : "222"}
    });
});
}
```

But it doesn't work as expected, and has the following problems:

1. The script runs repeatedly. (I wanted it run only once on each new tab)
2. Even if I click the "+" icon to create a new tab, the script will
   run. (I wanted it only run when clicking the icon I created on the toolbar)

I have also tried to change 'ready' to 'activiate', the repeated running problem is gone, but every time I create the tab, the script will run.

Many thanks to any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you're listening to the `ready` event of any and all tabs, rather than the one you just opened. One option is to do something like this:

```
function handleClick(state) {
    tabs.open({
        url: "about:blank",
        onOpen: function onOpen(tab) {
            tab.attach({
                contentScriptFile: self.data.url("home.js"),
                contentScriptOptions: {"aaa" : "1111", "bob" : "222"}
            });
        }
    });
}
```

And attach the script using the `onOpen` handler. For more info the docs are here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#open%28options%29

Comment: Awesome, it worked well! It took me all day, but couldn't find the answer. Your help make it easier and reliable for me. Many thanks!

Comment: Just curios, if I change "onOpen" to "onReady", it will keep sending requests repeatedly. (In home.js, I create a form, and submit the form in POST method). Just wondering why it is happening.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean "it will keep sending requests repeatedly". What will? The form in home.js? I'd be cautious about the behavior of `onReady` as I didn't see it documented.